# i am trying to add integers in my list in ascendant order!!any help pleasee?

Tags: c, list, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

i am trying to make a list that order integers in  ascendant order during the insertation phase ,for some reason it gives me a wierd number after putting the list in the right order,can someone tell me where i messed up?or if you have any optimal version of this function`ajout_liste_croissant()`?

```
#include"liste.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>
void ajout_liste_croissant(element**l,int info)
{assert(*l);
element*nouv;
nouv=(element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
if(vide(*l))/*if list is empty will add the new info without comparing */
  {
*l=nouv;
(*l)->cle=info;
(*l)->suivant=NULL;}
else
{element*courant,*q;
int inter;
courant=*l;
int trouve=0;
while(courant!=NULL&&!trouve)/*parcouring the list till the end or when finding a value bigger than the entered one*/
    {if(info<courant->cle)
trouve=1;
else{q=courant;/*this pointer get the adress of the previous current position in the list*/
courant=courant->suivant;}}/*the current pointer move to next adress*/
    if(trouve)
    {inter=courant->cle;
    courant->cle=info;/*exchanging values in case current positon is bigger than the entered value*/
    info=inter;
    nouv->cle=info;
    nouv->suivant=courant->suivant;
    courant->suivant=nouv;
    }
else
    /*if the list reaches end*/
    {
    nouv->cle=info;
    q->suivant=nouv;/*adding the new element at the end of the list*/
    nouv->suivant=NULL;}
}
}
void afficher(element*l)
{assert(!vide(l));
while(l!=NULL)
   {printf("%d\n",l->cle);
l=l->suivant;}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not too many errors. But your code is **absolutely unreadable**. I do not know how you could read it and, therefore, debug it.

So, I added spaces, indentations, new lines ... and it works with minor changes. I let you discover these changes. This answer is not necessarily the best way to do it but, starting from your code, I tried to do the minimum of changes. Moreover, avoid French (text, function names, ...) in your code when you ask question on stackoverflow.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

typedef struct element {
    int cle;
    struct element *suivant;
} element;

void creer_liste(element **l) {
    assert(l);
    *l=NULL;
}

int vide(element *l) {
    return(l==NULL);
}

void ajout_liste_croissant(element **l,int info) {
    assert(l);
    element *nouv;
    nouv=(element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
    if( vide(*l) ) {
        *l=nouv;
        (*l)->cle=info;
        (*l)->suivant=NULL;
    } else {
        element *courant,*q;
        int inter;
        courant=*l;
        int trouve=0;
        while ( courant != NULL && !trouve ) {
            if(info<courant->cle)
                trouve=1;
            else {
                q=courant;
                courant=courant->suivant;
            }
        }
        if(trouve) {
            inter=courant->cle;
            courant->cle=info;
            info=inter;
            nouv->cle=info;
            nouv->suivant=courant->suivant;
            courant->suivant=nouv;
        } else {
            nouv->cle=info;
            q->suivant=nouv;
            nouv->suivant=NULL;
        }
    }
}

void afficher(element *l) {
    assert(!vide(l));
    while(l!=NULL) {
        printf("%d\n",l->cle);
        l=l->suivant;
    }
}

int main() {
    element *data;
    int nb,info;
    creer_liste(&data);
    printf("donner la taille de la liste:\n");
    scanf("%d",&nb);
    for(int i=0;i<nb;i++) {
        printf("donner un entier:\n");
        scanf("%d",&info);
        ajout_liste_croissant(&data,info);
    }
    printf("_____________________\n");
    afficher(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by myself already, I found out that I messed up with the pointers and adresses in functions `creer_liste() ` and `vide() ` I forgot to answer here my question I just fixed it in my own program but thank you for spending your time and trying to understand my unreadable code.